# switch < или > в (int)

Tags: php

Возможно ли в `switch` сделать проверку на `<` ( больше ) или `>` ( меньше )

Я знаю что можно:

```
<?php
if(...) {}

Значение > 0 ? 'Группа' : 'Пользователь';
Значение > 2000000 ? 'Беседа' : null;
?>
```

Но у меня приходит значение в виде числа (int)

Вопрос: возможно ли в `switch` проверять `< >`?

Пример:
Мне от вк приходит значение:

```
1) больше 0: пользователь
2) меньше 0: группа
3) больше чем 20000000: беседа
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой смысл от этого? Прочитайте внимательно про оператор `switch`.

Comment: Скорее всего: я не получил ответ из за того что не выдал варианты

Comment: Больше `0`, на сколько больше? (может там `1` всегда приходит). Меньше `0`, на сколько меньше? (может там всегда `-1` приходит). Может там и массива хватит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть вариант `switch (true)`:

```
switch (true) {
    case $a > 100:
        echo 'gt 100';
        break;

    case $a > 10:
        echo 'gt 10';
        break;

    case $a > 0:
        echo 'gt 0';
        break;
}
```

Но тут надо правильно расположить условия, чтобы вы не попали в выполняющееся, но ненужное. Например, если расположить кейсы в обратном порядке (от 0 к 100), то при `$a = 101` - мы попадем в `gt 0`.

Comment: Я бы ещё `default`  добавил

Comment: default нужен в тех случаях, когда есть вероятность проскока всех case. А тут какбэ без вариантов.

Comment: Меньше 0 вот и проскочил.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 10;
switch ($a > 5):
    case true:
        echo 'true';
        break;
    case false:
        echo 'false';
        break;
endswitch;
```

Только зачем `switch`, если есть `if`?

```
$a = 10;
echo ($a > 5) ? true : false; // 1(true)
```

Comment: `echo ($a > 5)`?

Comment: @u_mulder а действительно, зачем тут тернарник)

Comment: `$a > 5` __уже возвращает__ `true`/`false`.

Comment: вдруг ему нужно что-то по условию выполнять, яж хз. для наглядности.